# How to get response in json with reference key models in WCF?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, rest, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want to get the response of the Model & reference model in json format from the Restful WCF service..

My model as below

// Role : User

```
[DataContract]
 public class User
    {

        [DataMember]
        public int Id {get; set;}

        [DataMember]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Password { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Designation { get; set; }
}
```

// Role : Model

```
[DataContract]
    public class Role
    {

        public Role()
        { }


        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]

        public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

// UserRole : Model

```
[DataContract]
    public class UserRole
    {
         public UserRole()
        {}


        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

Here what exactly I want to do.
when any client call method 
Method: AssignRoleToUser with Form parameter "UserID" & "RoleId"
at that time I inserting new record to UserRole Entity and return object with json.
currently below JSON string output as response.

**Current Output**

```
{
  "Id": 2, 
  "Level": 0,
  "RoleId": 3,
  "UserId": 2
}
```

I want like below

```
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Level": 0,
  "RoleId": [
    {
      "Id": 5,
      "Name": "Project Leader"
    }
  ],
  "UserId": [
    {
      "Designation": "System User",
      "Email": "abhishek@domain.com",
      "Gender": 0,
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "System User",
      "Password": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not change RoleId to navigation property Role and put Role object in it? The same with User

Comment: @Mardok Ok. I think like it. but whenever get the json we need to get that setter propery and return with that service call?  let me check it

Comment: @Mardok Is there a way to bind it while binding the UserRole  model. is any auto mapper tool to make easy.

Comment: Bhalan Your example code is not enough to see how you bind it. For example if you use EF code first usually you have reference ID property and navigation property or just navigation property. Check [this](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first) post

Comment: @Mardok thank you for good help. I hope given post link help me. i will look into it